# Spring Boot and dynamic compilation in Chronicle Wire

Tags: spring-boot, chronicle, chronicle-queue, chronicle-wire

Referring to the title above. To get Chronicle wire dynamic compilation to work with springboot, it requires you to unpack chronicle jars unto a temp directory so that the platform compiler can see classes from the fat JAR. Referring to the docs [here](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire#spring-boots-and-dynamic-compilation-in-chronicle-wire) it can be achieved by using `requiresUnpack` in bootJar task like below

```
requiresUnpack( "**/chronicle-*.jar")
```

After deploying the application. I have confirmed that the relevant jars are extracted to the temp directory as pictured below

[image]

However, I am still getting warnings with the generated code for method reader and writers:

`Failed to compile generated method reader - falling back to proxy method reader. Please report this failure as support for proxy method readers will be dropped in x.25`

Only when I run the project with the generated code will the warnings disappear.

My question is why do I still have to manually copy the generated code to make it work?

**Gradle bootJar task:**

[image]

Comment: Please share more details about: 1. "deploying the application" 2."Only when I run the project with the generated code..." 3. "Manually copy"

Comment: The generated code mentioned are proxies that are auto generated by Chronicle-Wire. Wire will work with those proxy classes at runtime. Unpacking the jars should help chronicle-wire's use of the platform compiler to generate this proxies automatically. You can read more [here](https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire#spring-boots-and-dynamic-compilation-in-chronicle-wire)

Comment: 1. Gradle command? 2. What is the difference/gradle command? 3. From/to?

Comment: Edited question with gradle task

Comment: Running the application via `Java -jar`

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine - see See also https://github.com/OpenHFT/Chronicle-Wire#spring-boots-and-dynamic-compilation-in-chronicle-wire